# How do I call a vb dll from C in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C program in Visual Studio 2010.  I created an empty project in visual studio 2010.  I add some .C files and some .h files.  I would like to call an existing vb dll from the C.  Is it possible? Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: vb6 or vb.net they are completely different beasts?

Answer (score 0):

Calling a C DLL from VB is described by Microsoft :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106553/en-us

Similarly, you can call managed code (VB, C#...) from C++ :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/en-us

HTH.

Comment: Is there anyway to make calls to the vb dll from C? I'd like to leave all my file extensions .C instead of changing them to .cpp.